# Spring, Angular.js 415 Unsupported Media Type Error

Tags: angular, spring, rest, http-status-code-415

This simple request encounters with a 415 Unsuppoerted Media Type error.

http://localhost:8080/semantic/api/getLastfmGraph/1

Here is my Controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getLastfmGraph/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Object getLastfmGraph(@PathVariable Long userId) throws Exception {
        User user = semanticGraphDao.findUserById(userId);

        List<Node> nodes = lastfm.topArtistsByUser(user.getLastfmUsername());
        List<Link> links = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Node n : nodes) {
            for (Node n2 : nodes) {
                if(!StringUtils.equals(n.getName(),n2.getName()))
                    links.add(new Link(n, n2, 1.0));
            }
        }

        return new Graph(nodes,links);
    }
```

Comment: API expect `Content-Type` header with value `application/json`

Comment: I solved it by removing consumes='application/json'

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing consumes='application/json'.